# How to assign two users to access the controller action in yii framework

Tags: php, yii, frameworks

I am using yii and i am new to this framework , I want to know how can i provide the access for the multiple users to use the particular action , Here is the code

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(


            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin,manoj'),  
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),

        );
    }
```

it id working if i use only the admin user or only manoj username but not working for both usernames, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for this question , I have to use this code

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(


            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
                'users'=>array('admin','manoj'),  
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),

        );
    }
```